# How do I register my Google Account in the AVD android emulator running 2.1 Google api level 7?

Tags: android, gmail, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm using the image "Google APIS (Google Inc)" (Android 2.1).
Using the Android SDK and AVD Manager, I create a new virtual machine with this image.
When I go to Settings --> Account, there is not the possibility to create ad Exchange Account, but I need a Google Account.

Any idea? :-O

Comment: I do not believe that was supported for Android 2.1. Note that Android 2.1 is on only 2.2% of Android devices, as of the February 2013 dashboard.

Comment: Ok, do you suggest me upgrading my android:minSdkVersion from 7 to 8?

Comment: It is more that you should think about your overall strategy. Perhaps you specifically *want* to support Android 2.1 because competitors will not. I cannot tell you what will work best for your business model. However, I suspect that most developers will not worry about Android 2.1 for new apps at this point in time.

Comment: My app use the user's google account to give him a "silent" unique id, without bother him with the process to create a new account, etc... So to know his gmail address is central for my app... So maybe it's sensed to upgrade android:minSdkVersion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CommonsWare says:

> I do not believe that was supported for Android 2.1. Note that Android
>   2.1 is on only 2.2% of Android devices, as of the February 2013 dashboard